# QGIS Expression CASE WHEN AND AND

Tags: qgis, expression, conditional, case

I am failing at making a case with many (3) conditions. I have different contract cases (f.e. Nutzungsvertrag) and i want to create a virtual column where contracts of a certain type are summed up with the number 2 and some with the numer 1 or else NULL. But the case with 3 conditions, I get no results, though there are certainly the cases. only if there was one AND... i am not sure about if there is a restriction, but maybe you can see the point and the problem, why i am only getting 1 and NULL as a result...

```
CASE 
  WHEN "Vertragsart" = 'Nutzungsvertrag' AND "versendet am" IS NOT NULL AND "gezeichnet am" IS NULL THEN 2
  WHEN "Vertragsart" = 'Nutzungsvertrag' AND "gezeichnet am" IS NOT NULL THEN 1
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: Check that you really have null value and not empty value (you may try to select by expression with ["gezeichnet am" IS NULL] and ["gezeichnet am"=''] to see what you have) then adapt your expression depending on the result (if you have a mix of null and empty value you will need to test for both with an OR operator in between and add parenthesis as needed)

Answer (score 6):

```
CASE 
  WHEN ("Vertragsart" = 'Nutzungsvertrag' AND "versendet am" IS NOT NULL AND "gezeichnet am" IS NULL) THEN 2
  WHEN ("Vertragsart" = 'Nutzungsvertrag' AND "gezeichnet am" IS NOT NULL) THEN 1
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Adding the paranthesis around the `WHEN` parts should suffice. If the expression still doesn't work, put paranthesis around each part connected by an `AND`, too.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for the response, but I had no luck with that. Don't know why and even  tried the paranthesis around each part too... could the problem be relying to the fact, that the "versand am" and "gezeichnet am" columns are dates?

Comment: Could you provide mock up data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I assumed the preview would be representative... after running the calcualtion it worked.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If the question is resolved, feel free to mark the helpful answer as solution. Another tiny bit of code of conduct: Please refrain from adding comments as answers, since it can be quite confusing ;-) thank you!